# NgModelOptions + Currency Filter = Field not displaying model

Tags: angularjs, filter, currency, directive

I have several form fields which need to be displayed in USD ($n.nn), and have used a custom currency directive successfully. But I've added NgModelOptions to control debounce:

> { updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default':100, 'blur': 0 } }"

This works fine EXCEPT when the field is updated then exited rapidly, in which case the prior value displays. Entering then leaving the field will then cause the correct value to display.

Any ideas on how to combine a directive or currency filter with NgModelOptions so the value displayed reflects the model value on exit?

Here's the current directive:

```
.directive('ngCurrency', function ($filter, $locale) {
      return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
          min: '=min',
          max: '=max',
          ngRequired: '=ngRequired'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

          function decimalRex(dChar) {
            return RegExp("\\d|\\" + dChar, 'g');
          }

          function clearRex(dChar) {
            return RegExp("((\\" + dChar + ")|([0-9]{1,}\\" + dChar + "?))&?[0-9]{0,2}", 'g');
          }

          function decimalSepRex(dChar) {
            return RegExp("\\" + dChar, "g");
          }

          function clearValue(value) {
            value = String(value);
            var dSeparator = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.DECIMAL_SEP;
            var clear = null;

            if (value.match(decimalSepRex(dSeparator))) {
              clear = value.match(decimalRex(dSeparator))
                      .join("").match(clearRex(dSeparator));
              clear = clear ? clear[0].replace(dSeparator, ".") : null;
            }
            else if (value.match(decimalSepRex("."))) {
              clear = value.match(decimalRex("."))
                      .join("").match(clearRex("."));
              clear = clear ? clear[0] : null;
            }
            else {
              clear = value.match(/\d/g);
              clear = clear ? clear.join("") : null;
            }

            return clear;
          }

          ngModel.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
            cVal = clearValue(viewValue);
            return parseFloat(cVal);
          });

          element.on("blur", function () {
            element.val($filter('currency')(ngModel.$modelValue));
            scope.$apply();
          });

          ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
            return $filter('currency')(value);
          });

          scope.$watch(function () {
            return ngModel.$modelValue;
          }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            runValidations(newValue);
          });

          function runValidations(cVal) {
            if (!scope.ngRequired && isNaN(cVal)) {
              return;
            }
            if (scope.min) {
              var min = parseFloat(scope.min);
              ngModel.$setValidity('min', cVal >= min);
            }
            if (scope.max) {
              var max = parseFloat(scope.max);
              ngModel.$setValidity('max', cVal <= max);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: Some more info would be great. Perhaps the code of your filter and how you display the field value?

Comment: @Itmar - yes, I didn't give much to go on. I think it has to do with the filter/directive looking at the $modelValue before the update. I will amend the question to include the directive.

Answer (score 0):

```
element.on("blur", function () {
        element.val($filter('currency')(ngModel.$modelValue));
        scope.$apply();
      });
```

What I assume is happening is that you are changing a field and leaving it, which causes the digest cycle to trigger - and that makes the scope.$apply() inside your event callback try to execute while it is already being executed. A workaround to this is usually to wrap the whole call in a $timeout.

```
element.on("blur", function () {
        $timeout(function() {
             element.val($filter('currency')(ngModel.$modelValue));
             scope.$apply();
        });
      });
```

I'm pretty sure that when this happens the console will display some kind of error message - for future reference.

Is there any reason why you are not using the filter directly on the model such as: {{ my.model | currency }} instead of adding an event? Seems like bad practice.

Comment: No error is generated. 
I can't put the filter on the model, as I'm working with a text field for display and a numeric value in the model.
I'm prepared to take an entirely different approach if needed - but I need a currency display and a numeric value on the back end.

Comment: Your suggested code does error out: Uncaught ReferenceError: $timeout is not defined - but I share your opinion that the problem lies in that section. The ngModel.$modelValue is pulling the pre-updated value since the model doesn't update until angular processes the blur - which happens after the DOM event fires. The question is, where can I grab the value prior to the update?

Comment: You need to inject $compile... same place you injected $filter and $locale: `.directive('ngCurrency', function ($filter, $locale, $compile) {`

Comment: that made no change at all. If the field is exited too quickly, the prior value is displayed. If you then re-enter and leave the field, the display adjusts to the correct (model) value.

Comment: can you create a plunkr?